# Why i am getting Error when creating mac file using py2app module?

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to convert Tkinter python file to dmg or mac os file.
But when I am typing **python setup.py py2app -A** in terminal I am getting following error
*** creating application bundle: MyApplication ***
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/mohamedthoufeeq/dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication'
Please help me how to solve this problem.

```
Mohameds-MacBook-Pro:~ mohamedthoufeeq$ python setup.py py2app -A
running py2app
creating /Users/mohamedthoufeeq/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/mohamedthoufeeq/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/mohamedthoufeeq/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
*** creating application bundle: MyApplication ***
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/mohamedthoufeeq/dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication'
```

Answer (score 1):

Four possible answers:

1. Write `python3` instead of `python`
2. Disable SIP as it may mess with the permission end (what your error suggests)

> Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R keys simultaneously after you
> hear the startup chime, this will boot Mac OS X into Recovery Mode
> When the “MacOS Utilities” / “OS X Utilities” screen appears, pull
> down the ‘Utilities’ menu at the top of the screen instead, and choose
> “Terminal” Type the following command into the terminal then hit
> return:
>
> `csrutil disable; reboot`

> You’ll see a message saying that System
> Integrity Protection has been disabled and the Mac needs to restart
> for changes to take effect, and the Mac will then reboot itself
> automatically, just let it boot up as normal

3. Remove the restricted File Flag

`sudo chflags -R norestricted /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

4. Uninstall py2app and reinstall it

`pip3 uninstall py2ap`

`pip3 install -U py2app`

Comment: Thank you for the solution first step has worked out and setup file is installed. But there is another error occurs when I put command open -a dist/MyApplication.app                              the error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mohamedthoufeeq/MyApplication.py'
2021-05-11 13:26:38.414 MyApplication[57965:3303221] MyApplication Error canypu tell me why this occurs please.

Comment: it searches for a file named "MyApplication.app" and it doesnt find it.

Comment: can you please mark it as answered? I solved your original problem, and gave a hint for your other problem. Without knowing your exact setup and I can't fix it, and its also an broad problem which has to be fixed by you.